# Is there a way Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync(); not to return null in android project using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

The problem is in the android project. I don't have such a problem in the iOS project.

Each time the variable from the GPS returns me: `null`

I read an article given to me by a user on stackoverflow:  https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/519, But it was not very clear to me how to solve the problem.

This is my code from the GPS button:

```
 async Task ButtonClickedGPS()
    {
        
        var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && status == PermissionStatus.Disabled)
        {
            _ = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

                if (location != null)
                {
                    WeatherBindingData weatherBindingData = await _restServiceForecast.GetWeatherDataForecast(GenerateRequestUriGPS(Constants.OpenWeatherMapEndpoint, location), GenerateRequestUriForecast(ConstantsForecast.OpenWeatherMapEndpoint2, _cityEntry), GenerateRequestUriAir(ConstantsAir.OpenWeatherMapEndpoint3, location));
                   
                    var CityName = weatherBindingData.WeatherDataCurrent.Title.ToString();
                    
                    _cityEntry.Text = CityName;

                   await DisplayHourlyForecast();
                }
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                // Handle not supported on device exception
            }
            catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
            {
                // Handle not enabled on device exception
            }
            catch (PermissionException pEx)
            {
                // Handle permission exception
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Unable to get location
            }
        }
```

The logic of the button is simple: I take the coordinates from the phone's GPS, pass them to API and it returns the name of the settlement to its coordinates, after which I attach the name to a search.
I didn't have any problems with the iOS project, but with Android `var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();` is coming: `null`.

How can I fix this problem? From the topic I attached as a hyperlink, I think I understood that the user's GPS should be turned off when starting the application, but this does not work for me

Comment: Did you call `GetLocationAsync()` first? Otherwise, I don't think it will return anything.

Comment: Can you give me some example ?

Comment: `Geolocation.GetLocationAsync()`

Comment: from the Github issue I pointed you to - "It is completely possible that it returns null and you should check against it as the provider may have cleared it out. This is working as intended.".  As @Cheesebaron points out there are other ways of getting location - `GetLastKnownLocationAsync()` is simply uses the last cached location, which is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(); still return null

Comment: What alternatives do I have left?

Comment: does your device have a GPS?  Is it enabled and do you have permissions?  Have you tried the sample app?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

Comment: My gps have been disabled, but now works great ! Thanks ! If you want post your comment like a answer I will accept you !